Is Hadamard gate considered a valid beam splitter when dealing with multiple beam splitters?
I have read that Hadamard gate can be a valid 50:50 beam splitter when dealing with one beam splitter , however when dealing with more than one beam splitter the Hadamard gate is no longer valid and we need to use other 50:50 beam splitter like the one with the matrix :
\begin{pmatrix}
1\over\sqrt{2} &  i\over\sqrt{2} \\
i\over\sqrt{2} & 1\over\sqrt{2}  \\
\end{pmatrix}
. From what I have read, it has to do with something related to phase shift in the beam splitter , here what is the explanation says : "Real beam splitters often introduce phase shifts between the reflected and transmitted beams. The Hadamard gate, however, does not introduce a phase shift, as it only alters the amplitudes without affecting the relative phase between the paths." So my question is, is Hadamard gate no longer a valid beam splitter when dealing with multiple beam splitters ? What does the explanation I quoted mean and why doesn't the Hadamard gate introduce a phase shift?

Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please properly format your matrix using MathJax? As it is currently written, it is hard to understand what make rows and columns, rather it seems to be some vector.

Hi welcome. It is also important that whenever you write things like “I have read that…” or “here’s what the explanation says…” you include references of where you saw this to provide context to your stayements

Cross posted https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/825554/291677

@Martin Vesely  -
I edited it

@ diemilio -  My treacher said we can't use multipe hadamard gates as beam s[litters  and the reason was somethin that has to do with the phase . I used ChatGPT and it said someting similar (what I quoted is from the answer from GPT) , could you please explain the phase issue with Hadamard gate ?
